# Log4Net: How to get Logger?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have been using Log4Net for several months, and I create a new Logger as a member variable for each class, like this:

```
// Member variables
private readonly ILog m_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyClass");
```

Then I invoke the logger from each method in the class that logs, like this:

```
// Initialize
m_Logger.Info("MyClass.MyMethod() invoked.");
...
m_Logger.Debug("MyClass.MyMethod() did something...");
...
m_Logger.Info("MyClass.MyMethod() completed.");
```

Is there any reason not to use this approach, or is there a better way to set up the logger? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your logger should probably be static, and you can take advantage of other overrides, such as using the type:

```
private static readonly ILog m_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

For improved performance, you should also check the log level you are in before calling the appropriate log function.  For example:

```
if (m_Logger.IsDebugEnabled) { m_Logger.DebugFormat("Starting {0}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString()); }
```

The above example also shows using reflection to get the method name.

Comment: 'using reflection to get the method name' - but you don't need to ask reflection to do a stack walk and consult the assembly metadata for the method name: you just typed it into the source file

Comment: It's just an example. Using reflection allows for simple cut-and-paste of the line to a multitude of places without having to edit the line for the correct method name.